# Custom Title Bar Context Menu Actions

Tags: windows, shell, contextmenu, titlebar

I want to add custom actions to every window's title bar context menu.  The goal is to add an option like in the task view where you can move a window to a different virtual desktop.  I was able to do this with hotkeys using GlobalHotKey and WindowsDesktop packages in C#.  But I want to do it in the UI as well similar to some Linux desktop environments.

I know you cannot normally do this with the registry like you can with other context menus.  When creating your own application I know you can use `GetSystemMenu`, `AppendMenu`, etc. and override `WndProc` to handle it.  But this obviously will not work for what I am intending.

The application Moo0 Window Menu Plus achieves the desired effect but I have no idea how they do it.

I have a feeling the solution is probably somewhat hacky but I would still like to know how it could be done.  I am open to using any language to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inject into the process, that is the only way to add a menu item.

A shell [hook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx) will notify you with `HSHELL_WINDOWCREATED` when a appropriate window has been created. You can then inject into the process (with another hook type or `CreateRemoteThread`). Once you have your .DLL in the process you can subclass the window and change the system menu.

You need to create both a 32-bit and 64-bit injection .DLL and I would recommend that you write it in native code, not C#.